# How to style a QWizard's button area?

Tags: css, qt

I have an application with styles set in a qss file. All widget backgrounds are now a darker colour and buttons have their own styles too.

This is all working throughout the software except for on QWizard which seems to have its own button area across the bottom of the wizard with the default qt widget colour still applied to it.

I have looked at the various components that i can apply styles to on the QWizard but none of them seem to be this button area across the bottom of the form, just wondering if anyone has encountered this before and found out which object i need to apply the style for to change the colour of this area.

[image]

Comment: What style did you try? `QWizard {background: red}` works for me.

Comment: That seems like an obvious thing to try... Since id already set the style for QWidget i was expecting the unstlyed bit to be a button area or navigation bar or something i needed to style, i will try it now and let you know if it works post as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: I am using a .qss stylesheet for the entire program that is applied in main, not setting the style inline. i have tried setting background colour, and QWizard page background colour and neither make a difference

Comment: Temporary remove your style and set only `* {background: red}`. This should affect every single widget.

Comment: Removed entire style sheet and set everything to red like you suggested and it's not changed its style I guess that means you can't change the style then?

Comment: This is very strange, as if Qt would use a native Windows component for buttons area. I will try on Windows myself and let you know.

Comment: Cheers @svlasov seems like weird behaviour can't figure it out

Comment: We need your code if you want help :)

Comment: no you dont, read the comments, i have started a completely new project with just a QWizard in it and tried to apply styles to it with no luck on changing the colour of the bottom bar, this is a completely generic question that isnt a result of buggy code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set wizard style to `ClassicStyle` then `QWidgets` are available for colorization with `QSS`.

```
wizard->setWizardStyle(QWizard::ClassicStyle);
```

For default `VistaStyle` painting hardcoded in source of `QWizard` like this:

```
if (wizardPrivate->isVistaThemeEnabled(QVistaHelper::VistaBasic)) {
    if (window()->isActiveWindow())
        painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(169, 191, 214)), 0)); // ### hardcoded for now
    else
        painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(182, 193, 204)), 0)); // ### hardcoded for now
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, width(), 0);
}
```

[Code on Github](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qwizard.cpp)

Comment: Only just got round to testing this today, and it worked perfectly thank you, bounty awarded